# .net regex specifing number of digits in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

hello i am trying to find a match in the followig format in a text file using regex and save the number into a variable.

```
id='12341234321234131313'
```

now my problem i want to consider the string a match only if the integer has a number digits between 16 and 22, is it possible to do this directly using regex or do i have to check for the length?

i would use the following if to match when the number of digits is 20

```
Dim rex = New Regex("id='(\d{20})'")
```

but what about between 2 numbers?

Comment: How much effort did you put into trying to find this out for yourself? [Quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for a range of repeat lengths, use `{min,max}`:

```
"cid='(\d{16,22})'"
```

Comment: You can also omit one of them. e.g. `\d{,22}` (0-22 digits) or `\d{16,}` (16+ digits).